# PostgreSQL query on column with index longer than without

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have a simple table created as follow :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."bench2" (
      "tags_text_1" text[],
      "tags_text_2" text[]
)
```

And I have an index on the first column created like that :

```
CREATE INDEX "idx_tags_text_1" ON "public"."bench2" USING gin ("tags_text_1")
```

I insert 15 millions rows, with 1 to 10 random string as tag1, tag2, ..., tag10 and insert the same elements in both columns, so tags_text_1 is always the same as tags_text_2

I'm using Postgres on my 2017 Mac Book Pro, version:

```
PostgreSQL 10.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), 64-bit
```

I'm trying to query on the two fields like that :

```
SELECT count(*) from bench2 WHERE tags_text_1 && ARRAY['tag1']
```

[Explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/nouK)

```
SELECT count(*) from bench2 WHERE tags_text_2 && ARRAY['tag1']
```

[Explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/lCJf)

This two queries don't use the index and take 4 seconds each

```
SELECT count(*) from bench2 WHERE tags_text_1 @> ARRAY['tag1']
```

[Explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Rfrk)

```
SELECT count(*) from bench2 WHERE tags_text_2 @> ARRAY['tag1']
```

[Explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/RCHy)

This two queries don't use the index and take 4 seconds each too

```
SELECT count(*) from bench2 WHERE tags_text_1 <@ ARRAY['tag1']
```

[Explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/pspjS)

```
SELECT count(*) from bench2 WHERE tags_text_2 <@ ARRAY['tag1']
```

[Explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/R2VY)

The first one use the index and takes 8.5 seconds and the second one don't use index and take 2.8 seconds.

I don't get it. Why only the <@ operator is using the index? And why is the query using the index the longest to execute?
I'm trying to optimize the queries to search for row where tags match a least one tag, so the &&.
Any idea what's going on? Is there PostgreSQL configuration I should be aware of (The index size is 100 Mb for 15 Millions records). I have to admit that I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plans generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a simple "explain"). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please consider instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Edited as requested :)